# How to put plenty of data (page content) into DB in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I'm starting an adventure with ASP.NET and I'm creating mini CMS system just to be able to change content of website by logging into panel and changing content of appropriate page.
The problem is that I have field in column in my database which is type of "text" and I cannot put there any page content that is divided into lines (content text, html markups and so). When I try to copy/paste operation into that field in table (in Server Explorer in VS 2010) it only copies first line of text, nothing more. Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Which database you are using? "Text" data type in SQL Server is obsolete. Why not use Varchar(MAX)?

You may also consider [BLOB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895234.aspx).

There are many [open-source ASP.NET CMS apps](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/content-managment-systems) which you can refer.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Database. I don't need to store a big amount of data. It's circa about few dozens lines of text

Comment: I have not tried it personally but I think BLOB things should work. In SQL Server 2008 there is FileStream type which is suitable for unstructured data.

Comment: +1 for changing Text to (n)varchar. It will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider user Entity Framework.  It is a simple, object-oriented way for developers to get data in the database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx

Here is another tutorial with a step-by-step guide.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489.aspx

Comment: but I didn't find any worth-seeing tutorial which shows how to create such database and how to use it in MVC (with all CRUD operations and showing extracted content in views, how to map database and so on) :/ I'm a newbie, so it would be better to see step-to-step tutorial. Do you know something worth considering?